# How do perform an "except" filter in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Suppose that I have an Angular view that allows a user to check books out of a library.  My data model consists of two arrays of `Book` entities which each have a unique ID field plus a title field.  The first array contains an entity for every book in the library and the second array contains an entity for every book that the user has checked out.

```
libraryBooks = [{
    id: 0,
    title: "The Adventure of Tom Sawyer"}, {
    id: 1,
    title: "Moby Dick" }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "To Kill a Mockingbird" }, {
    id: 3,
    title: "The Three Little Pigs" }];
checkedOutBooks = [{
    id: 0,
    title: "The Adventure of Tom Sawyer"}, {
    id: 3,
    title: "The Three Little Pigs" }];
```

In short, the library has four books and the user has checked out two.  If I want to list the books from both arrays, I can write this:

```
<h1>Library Books</h1>
<div ng-repeat="book in libraryBooks">
    {{ book.title }}
</div>
<h1>Checked out Books</h1>
<div ng-repeat="book in checkedOutBooks">
    {{ book.title }}
</div>
```

Suppose I want to display a third list: the subset of library books that the user has not checked out.

I have seen examples where the Angular "filter" is used to specify one particular value that should not be matched in order to narrow down a list, but in this case, I want to exclude multiple values, so how do I go about doing this?

I have seen examples where a custom filter is added to an Angular module, but I think that in this case, any custom filter should be scoped to this controller.

Comment: I have a similar example here that I wrote a few years ago: [controller](https://variouspublicexperiments.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WebTechs2013/WebApi/SiteScripts/Angular/ProductsController.js), [HTML](https://variouspublicexperiments.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WebTechs2013/WebApi/Views/Products/Angular.cshtml). The examples shows how to filter out deleted products.

Comment: In your example @Danny, it looks like you create a filter with the function setFilter.  How do you access it in your view?

Comment: Look at the HTML link in the comment edit, specifically `ng-class="{active: filterExp=='non-del'}" ng-click="setFilter('non-del')"` and `<div class="panel" ng-repeat="product in Products | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:filterFunc">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this figured out.  The solution is to write a filter function and attach it to $scope like so:

```
function filter_notCheckedOut(book) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < that.libraryBooks.length; i += 1) {
        if (that.libraryBooks[i].id === page.id) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the view, it can then be referenced like this:

```
<h1>Books not checked out</h1>
<div ng-repeat="book in libraryBooks | filter:filter_notCheckedOut">
    {{ book.title }}
</div>
```